# Can I make the software highlight questions with a given tag?

Tags: support, tagging

Whenever a question is tagged "algebraic geometry" it appears in blue when I'm logged in, probably because a large proportion of my answers are to questions so  tagged .
 At first I found that just an amusing diversion, but I realize that I'm now quite fond of that feature.
I was wondering if I could choose myself which tags I want to be highlighted.

Comment: I think it's under your user profile page > prefs. This link might work (I replaced my user id # with yours) http://math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/3217

Comment: +1. You are absolutely right, J.D. :  thanks a lot! If you upgrade  your comment to an answer, I'll be  delighted to upvote you and to accept your answer.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/blue-highlighted-questions-what-are-they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's under your user profile page > prefs. This link might work (I replaced my user id # with yours) math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/3217

Comment: Thanks again, J.D.

Answer (score 3):

You can add tags to the Favorite Tags list on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Thanks , Peter.